# Как создать форум?

Tags: php, html, css

Как создать форум на `php`? Какие коды нужны? Какие блоки создавать? надо ли подключаться к базе данных?

Comment: Чтобы создать форум, нужно сначала прочесть несколько книг по PHP, а затем практика, практика и еще раз практика.

Comment: @d1b2, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

может так попробовать :)

Answer (score 5):

Ого, вы меню на `html` и `css` осилить не можете, а уже на форум претендуете))

Используйте готовое решение [phpBB](http://bb3x.ru/).

База данных нужна, а еще вебсервер. Но чтоб довести его до ума, все равно надо знать `html`+`css`...

Answer (score 2):

Скачай готовый движок форума. Их много. Вообще я Вам бы посоветовал использовать проект [ucoz.ru](http://ucoz.ru). Там все уже готово. Сайт сделан специально для новичков.

Comment: да там ни так интересно как на php  темболее я там уже всё сделал у меня 3 сайта! я хочу вот на php создать!

Comment: Молодчинка то какой!:)

Comment: @lirik90 :) +1